# Install script for perl script

Tags: perl, build, makefile, installation

I have simple perl script and I want to make install script which install dependencies (perl modules) and copy my file.perl to `/usr/share/path` asking about password if necessary. I found that there are some solutions for installing perl modules (Makefile.PL, Build.PL etc.). But my script isn't module. How should I attempt it?

Comment: [I'll talk about this at YAPC::Europe](http://act.yapc.eu/ye2012/talk/4065)

Answer (score 4):

`Makefile.PL`/`ExtUtils::MakeMaker` support a `EXE_FILES` parm for perl script, you can  see how `App::Ack` do [this](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PETDANCE/ack-2.00a01/Makefile.PL) or check this [tutorial](http://www.vromans.org/johan/articles/makemaker.html). Just set the prefix to your directory and it should do the work for you.